Are the angle rotation ranges (-π/2, π/2) or (0, 2π) fixed when encoding classical data, or can they vary
I am running some experiments using quantum circuits, when it comes the input data encoding, I firstly tried the approaches I have read in some articles where the values for rotating the input is either (-π/2, π/2) or (0, 2π), I have tried both ranges where my input data were first normalized between (0, 1) both didn’t give me good results, but when I used a scale between **(0, π/2) it was good. And here comes the other thing, gradients computation was another problem where I used the parameter shift rule, from all recourses I have checked so far as in Qiskit documentation they used (π/2) as a shift value, however that also didn’t work fine for me until I checked using smaller shifts like (π/4 and π/8) I know that sometimes it is meaningless to use small shifts for gradients computation however these values where best for my model, my question is are we limited to use the common shifts or angle encoding scalers or we can use what’s most beneficial for our model?
